# How to add row number column to stimulsoft cross-tab

Tags: reporting-services, crosstab, stimulsoft

My problem is what I need to create cross-tab with row number column.
When I use `{Line}` expression, report groups all rows in one cell and paste 1 into.

[image]

Then, I found that I can put expression `{SqlDataSource.Position + 1}` in column value. When I did it I got table with normal row number, but report contained all rows from datasource (not grouped by cross-tab)

[image]

How I can add row number column in cross-tab?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the EnumeratorType property for the row of Cross-Tab.

Comment: Hello Aleksey. How I can use it? Do I need to create a column with some expression? Do I need to create a column with some expression?